# Move old site from root to subdirectory and install WordPress in the root (redirect conflicts)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I moved my old static site to a subdirectory named "old" and installed WordPress in the root directory. How can i redirect to the old site without creating conflicts with WordPress .htaccess?

Example:
mysite.com/myoldsitefile.htm should redirect to mysite.com/old/myoldsitefile.htm instead of to the 404 error page of WordPress site.

Comment: I suggest you Google for: "install wordpress in a subdirectory".

Comment: In this case my site will be available at mysite.com/newsitedirectory and i dont want that.

Comment: From experience I can tell you that installing wordpress in a sub-directory as an afterthought causes numerous problems. HTACCESS will only get you so far. The database of the old site needs to be updated as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Wordpress htaccess add the following (before the Wordpress rules):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule old/.* - [L]
```

This will [skip the next rules](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) for all URLs prefixed by `old/`.

***Update***

On top of this rule, you will have to add some rules to redirect your old url to the `old` folder:

```
# Redirect all .html and .htm
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/old[/]?
RewriteRule ^([^.]*).(html?) old/$1.$2 [R=301,L]
# Redirect everything that is in your images folder
RewriteRule ^medias/(.*) old/medias/$1 [R=301,L]
```

And so on.

Comment: It doesnt work. mysite.com/myoldsitefile.htm should redirect to mysite.com/old/myoldsitefile.htm instead of to the 404 error page of WordPress site.

Comment: It works, you just didn't explained that your old urls are not yet redirected to the old directory. Does all your old site urls finish with .htm?

Comment: No, .htm, .html, .jpeg, subdirectories/subfile.htm etc.

Comment: I edited my answer to give some examples of generic rewrite rules that you could use. But you will have to work on your own to build every rewrite rules for files that can't be match using generic catch up.

Comment: I get "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS". mysite.com/oldsitefile.html redirect to mysite.com/old/old/old/old/old/old/old/old/old/old/old/old/old/old/old/old/old/old/old/old/old/oldsitefile.html

Comment: Updated - added a rewritecond for the old folder.